# I need to sort Bootstrap grid rows by title

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that I have created in bootstrap 3 using the grid and NOT tables.

The website is for booking busses.

The table HTML structure looks something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3"><h3>Bus Company</h3></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"><h3>Bus Features</h3></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"><h3>Departure Time</h3></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"><h3>Book Now</h3></div>
</div>
```

And then there's a loop that gets all the relevant search results...one of the iterations looks like this:

```
<div class="row busses">
    <div class="col-lg-3"><p>Bus Company One</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"><p>Water, Toilet</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"><p>6:45 pm</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"><p>Book Now</p></div>
</div>
```

And that will repeat for every bus that matches the search criteria.

I would like to be able to click on any of the titles in the first row and then that sorts the results accordingly...or maybe just departure time and bus company (column 1 and column 3).

I have searched far and wide and ideally would just like a javascript plugin that I can use but everything I find seems to need to use an actual html `<table>` and I do not want to use that.

If anyone does know of a plugin it also needs to be able to sort by time as in...see that 2pm is later than 11am if you get what I mean.

Thanks in advance!

Matt

Comment: If your mission is to produce something like this on Bootstrap, you're most likely expected (if not, you should) to make it responsive, so that when you go to a mobile device, it will drop the columns underneath each other. This is what causes you more problems than generating the rows in general, since you will have to make your title row to work with the whole listing when you are on mobile view.

Comment: Well yeah...responsive is the reason I want to use divs instead of tables although in the mobile version the titles dissapear entirely so for the purpose of this...mobile does not have to be a consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for that answer...that code looks pretty good but I actually ended up finding this little script which ended up doing everything for me quite nicely...and its jQuery independant too!

http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

Answer (score 4):

This could be achieved with something like this:

```js
function sortBusses(byDatum, reverse) {
  var busses = $('.busses').detach().toArray();
  busses = busses.sort(function(a,b) {
    var aVal = $(a).find('[data-target-attr='+byDatum+']').text();
    var bVal = $(b).find('[data-target-attr='+byDatum+']').text();

    // looks reversed because we use append later, not prepend
    var returnVal = bVal < aVal ? 1 : -1;

    if (reverse) returnVal = -returnVal;
    return returnVal;
  });
  $(busses).appendTo('.busses-container');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.busses-heading div').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-target-attr')) {
      var isReversed = $(this).attr('data-reversed');
      reverse = (isReversed && isReversed==='false') ? true : false;
      sortBusses($(this).attr('data-target-attr'), reverse);
      $(this).attr('data-reversed', reverse);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="busses-container">
  <div class="row busses-heading">
      <div class="col-lg-3" data-target-attr="company"><h3>Bus Company</h3></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3" data-target-attr="features"><h3>Bus Features</h3></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3" data-target-attr="time"><h3>Departure Time</h3></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3"><h3>Book Now</h3></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row busses">
      <div class="col-lg-3"><p data-target-attr="company">Bus Company One</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3"><p data-target-attr="time">6:45 pm</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3"><p data-target-attr="features">Seats</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3"><p>Book Now</p></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row busses">
      <div class="col-lg-3"><p data-target-attr="company">Bus Company Two</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3"><p data-target-attr="time">7:45 pm</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3"><p data-target-attr="features">Water, Toilet</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3"><p>Book Now</p></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row busses">
      <div class="col-lg-3"><p data-target-attr="company">Bus Company Three</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3"><p data-target-attr="time">8:45 pm</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3"><p data-target-attr="features">Toilet</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3"><p>Book Now</p></div>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

However, since your data is tabular in nature, it would be advisable to go ahead and use a table